# What pattern can be used to create a set of related classes?

Tags: php, class, oop, interface, abstract

I posted this question earlier however it got closed due to being specific. So, I am going to try making it more general this time.

I am creating a number of classes that are going to be used to fetch data using various different API providers. I refer to these classes as "network" classes. Every network will be handled by an individual class. The reason for this is that the data provided by the APIs are going to be significantly different. So, it does seem to make sense to create individual classes that extend an abstract class which contains methods that will be the same.

However, in some cases, I don't need different classes for some networks because the API is exactly the same for these. The only difference is a couple of parameters. So obviously, for something so subtle, I don't want to create individual classes.

Right now, I load these networks using a function called get_networks() which returns an array of network class names. These classes are stored in an array and loaded later.

What is a pattern that I can use for this situation? To be more general, this question is related to classes that do the same job, however they do it differently. An exception is for some classes that have APIs that are very same. I wull appreciate all the help I receive.

I thought about using generators with an iterable class but I am not sure if that would be the right way of solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about creating classes, or creating instances of those classes?  I'm guessing the latter.

If you're looking for a maintainable way of creating these instances, including passing configuration information, perhaps a dependency injection container would help?  It would keep your configuration distinct from code.  Most PHP frameworks come with one, or you could roll your own.

Comment: I am talking about creating related but different classes, not instances. There are going to be up to 500 different classes that I need to create. This is because every API provider is different. They use different HTTP methods and headers, some use URL parameters whereas others require the parameters to be passed through the body. The data that is returned by them uses a significantly different structure as well so all classes need to take care of these APIs individually.

Except for a few of course. Their difference is subtle and doesn't make sense to separate them into different classes.